# How to construct these points with ruler and compass

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

In the image, $ABCD$ is a square, $AM=ME$ and $\angle CME = 90^{\circ}$

[image]

the original problem was to prove $\alpha = \frac 32 \theta$, but I'm more concerned with the construction of the figure. If $X = AC \cap ME, H = BD \cap CM $ then $H$ is orthocenter of $\triangle CXE$ which gives us a few cool circles, but I still need to use the fact that $AM=ME$ to figure out this construction. Any ideas?

Comment: To construct this figure using ruler and compass, $E$ is an arbitrary point on $BD$, then $M$ is the intersection of the line $AD$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AE$, and the rest follows.  $\quad$ I believe that in the limiting case of $E=D$, we have $ \theta = 0$ and $ \alpha \neq 0$, so the problem condition doesn't seem to hold.

Comment: I haven't looked too carefully at it yet but you may need to make a similarity argument between triangles AXM and DME and therefore use the fact that AM = ME.

Comment: @CalvinLin $\angle EMC = 90^{\circ}$

Comment: @Mark the triangles are not similar

Comment: @hellofriends Right, I wasn't quite clear what the statement of the problem is. As it turns out $E$ is not an arbitrary point on BD, but on specially chosen to make $\angle EMC = 90^\circ$ (which you didn't state outside of the image, so I didn't know if we could assume that)

Comment: @WillJagy I need to find $M$ first

Comment: @WillJagy $M$ is not an arbitrary point on $AD$ (which is similar to the confusion that I had). Essentially OP's question is how to construct the unique point $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to get the Co-ordinates "analytically" , to get insight on whether Construction is Possible & what Construction may work.

**Short Summary : It is not Possible !**

We can let $M$ move on $AD$ , then cut the arc with center $M$ having radius $AM$ to get the Point $E$ below the Square ,which indicates that $AM$ must be larger than half $AD$.

Let the Square Diagonal intersect @ the Origin to give this Image :

[image: Square + Diagonals]

The Square is shifted to make Origin the Center. The Side is then scaled to make it $1+1=2$. Hence the 2 Diagonals are the lines $y=x$ & $y=-x$.
Point M will have the Co-ordinates $(M,-1)$. Point E will have the Co-ordinates $(E,-E)$. Here $M$ must be Positive & $E$ must be larger than $1$.

When $M=0$ ( at the Mid-Point ) , $\angle CME$ is less than $90$.
When $M=1$ ( at $D$ ) , $\angle CME$ is more than $90$.
Somewhere in-between , $\angle CME$ must be $90$.

Writing the Equations :
$AM=ME$ :: $(1+M)^2=(M-E)^2+(E-1)^2$
$CM \perp ME$ :: $(1+1)/(1-M) \times (1-E)/(E-M) = -1$

Via Wolfram , the Unique Solution (Domain : Positive real) is very Cumbersome :

[image: SOLUTION]

**The Core Point which we get here : The Solution has Cube roots , hence it is not Possible to Construct with Compass+Straight-Edge.**